# Python Multiprocessing Pool Class won't work

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I am trying to use multiprocessing on a different problem but I can't get it to work. To make sure I'm using the Pool class correctly, I made the following simpler problem but even that won't work. What am I doing wrong here?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def square(x):
    sq = x**2
    return sq

def main():
    x1 = [1,2,3,4]
    pool = Pool()
    result = pool.map( square, x1 )
    print(result)

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

The computer just seems to run forever and I need to close and restart the IPython shell before I can do anything.

Comment: i run this code and it works,

Comment: You're in an IPython shell? multiprocessing doesn't work very well in an interactive session.

Comment: @user2357112 yes it works in ipython shell

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong. I named the script "multiprocessing.py" which is the name of the module that was being imported. This resulted in the script attempting to import itself instead of the actual module.

Comment: Can you maybe help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59892469/multiprocessing-for-webscrapping-wont-start-on-windows-and-mac